# How to version control report with a large dataset?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a report with a large dataset ( more than 100MB ) that I need to version control.
I would like only to vc the report and the empty dataset - containing the Power Query transformations.

I cannot apply incremental refresh to the dataset (given the nature of its data).

I know I could upload the dataset to PBI Service, and then use SSMS to empty the dataset, then download, but that doesn't sound very efficient.

Is there a 'correct' way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS recently introduced a new file format for PBI Desktop files. Instead of .pbix, you use .pbip. This new format is still in preview but it can be used and allows you to version control your desktop files in Git. You can read more here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/projects/projects-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/projects/projects-git

If you just want to save your desktop file without the data, you can save as a .pbit which saves the report visuals only.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm a little bit afraid of the Preview state: what possible downsides could involve? Is it safe to use it in a professional environemnt/project?

Comment: It is only recently released and I have seen reports of a few problems. I'd be cautious of using it in production until it goes general availability. I don't think that will be far away though so you could certainly start getting familiar with the process - just don't commit anything important without a backup. 
Don't forget to mark as solved - thanks.

Comment: I never forget. I just prefer to do it when I consider it solved. Thanks.